# MySQL - Left Join takes too long, how to optimize query?

Tags: mysql, innodb, join, select

A leader may have many followers. A `notification_followers` table gets a single notification when a leader adds a post with an entry `leader_id 1` and `notifiable_id 0` (id 1,2 in table). The same table gets a single notification when the current user `14` is followed by someone, with an entry `leader_id 0` and `notifiable_id 14` (id 3 in table).

`notification_followers` (*id is PRIMARY, each field except data is an index on its own*)

```
| id | uuid               | leader_id | notifable_id | data   | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 001w2cwfoqzp8F3... | 1         | 0            | Post A | 2018-04-19 00:00:00
| 2  | lvbuX4d5qCHJUIN... | 1         | 0            | Post B | 2018-04-20 00:00:00
| 3  | eEq5r5g5jApkKgd... | 0         | 14           | Follow | 2018-04-21 00:00:00
```

All the follower related notifications are in one place now which is perfect.

We need to now check if the user `14` is a follower of `leader_id 1` to know whether to show them notifications `1` and `2`. For that, we scan the `user_follows` table to see if the logged in user exists as a `followed_id` to the `leader_id` so they know about the notification, but only if they followed the leader **before** the notification was posted (new followers should not get older post notifications when the follow the user, only new ones).

`user_follows` *(id is PRIMARY, each field is an index on its own)*

```
| id | leader_id | follower_id | created_at
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | 14         |  2018-04-18 00:00:00 // followed before, has notifs
| 2  | 1         | 15         |  2018-04-22 00:00:00 // followed after, no notifs
```

The final thing to note, is the user should know if the notification was read or not, this is where the `notification_followers_read` table comes in. It stores the `follower_id` along with the `notification_uuid` for all read notifications, along with their `read_at` timestamp.

`notification_followers_read` *(composite index on notification_uuid, follower_id)*

```
| notification_uuid | follower_id | read_at
--------------------------------------------------------
  qIXE97AP49muZf... | 17          | 2018-04-21 00:00:00 // not for 14, we ignore it
```

We now want to return the latest 10 notifications ordered by the auto incrementing `nf.id` desc for user `14`. They should see all 3 notifications from `notification_followers`, since **non of them were read by this user yet**. The first 2, since they followed the leader **before** the leader made the posts, and the 3rd notification, since they were followed and their `notifiable_id` is `14`.

Here is the query which works, but take too long **~9 secs**:

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf
LEFT JOIN user_follows uf ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE (nf.created_at > uf.created_at OR notifiable_id = 14)
ORDER BY nf.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

`notification_followers` has ~100K records and we're using InnoDB. Here is the `EXPLAIN` for the query:

[image: Explain]

How can we optimize the query so it runs in a few ms?

**UPDATE WITH SQL DUMP**

[SQL DUMP TO REPRODUCE LOCALLY](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZktZNgM5CMfXVxp8Kjn_V7GfvErDujtx/view?usp=sharing) just create `speed_test` database locally and import file to see the slow query issue live with all the table data *(~100K rows)*.

Comment: Is follower_id a different value then notifable_id? It seems you are doing unneeded filtering by adding follower_id = 14 t both join clauses and that just doing notifable_id in the where clause should cover it,

Comment: @JoeW `14` is the currently logged in user in this case. In `user_follows` table they are `follower_id` to identify them with the `leader_id` there. In `notification_followers_read` table they are `follower_id` to identify them with the `notification_uuid`. In `notification_followers` they are `notifiable_id` only when a user follows them, not a new leader post, so we can identify that they were followed.

Comment: My point was it looks like there was an unneeded filter on both the user_follows and the notification_followers_read tables since you can put it in the where clause and filter it a single time rather then then it being filtered 3 times like it is now.

Comment: @Joe W: But reducing the cardinality of the sets to join as early as possible is likely to reduce the costs of the join.

Comment: The index on `notification_followers.id`, is it `DESC`? If not maybe try that. And/or maybe one on `notification_followers.notifiable_id ASC` and `notification_followers.created_at ASC`, one on `notification_followers_read.follower_id ASC` and `notification_followers_read.notification_uuid` and one on `user_follows.follower_id` and `user_follows.leader_id` (each combined). With more emphasis on the latter two.

Comment: @stickybit not sure what you mean, how do you put `DESC`/`ASC` on the index? We're just pulling out the final notifications in `DESC` by id for latest notification first. @Joe W Do you mean to move all the `= 14` of both joins to the where clause instead?

Comment: @Wonka: Check [the documentation on `CREATE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) (note the `[ASC | DESC]` for `index_col_name`). You might also/alternatively try to index `leader_id ASC`, `created_at ASC`, `uuid ASC` and `id DESC` on `notification_followers`.

Comment: @stickybit that seems to only work on `mysql 8.0` but I am on `mysql 5.7` and can't upgrade atm. I added an **UPDATE WITH SQL DUMP** section for easy local reproduction as well to see it locally btw.

Comment: That's to bad. Did any of the other three (`ON notification_followers (notifiable_id, created_at)`, `ON notification_followers_read (follower_id, notification_uuid)` and `ON user_follows (follower_id, leader_id)`) do any good? You might also try to create them with columns swept (first column becomes second and vice versa in the index expression). Sometimes the database likes to "read it from the other side".

Comment: I had a look at your dump. And I noticed your table sizes are rather "asymmetric" (~100k rows in `notification_followers` vs a handful in the others). It is for you to judge how realistic this distribution is. But I guess some more records wouldn't harm. With this few records in the other two tables a full table scan might actually come cheaper as any index biasing the result of the indexes' effects. And I couldn't find some of the indexes from the description of the tables in the OP ("each field is an index on its own"). My mistake or aren't they included?

Comment: So the indexes are there, but I turned them into compound indexes, like on the joins so it scans faster. I've been trying many combos, individual per field, then I did the compound indexes (which is what is in the dump atm) I am not 100% set on them, so they can be changed for the sake of improved performance. When taking out the `ORDER BY nf.id DESC` and leaving in the `LIMIT 10` the query takes ~200ms, but the order is not correct as it is `ASC`. So it makes me think that the asymmetricness of the data in tables is not an issue, but rather something with the order by or indexes...

Comment: Ah, my bad. The nameless indexes confused me. Well, so far I'm getting the best result with `CREATE INDEX nfr_fid_nuuid ON notification_followers_read (follower_id, notification_uuid);` and
`CREATE INDEX uf_fid_lid ON user_follows (follower_id, leader_id);` (and all the other indexes, except the primary ones, dropped). For `notification_followers` it used the `PRIMARY` index with me (which doesn't seem to be the case in the explain you posted?). I couldn't find anything better than `PRIMARY` so far. BTW: Tests were done on a v5.7.21 32 bit on Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for the help, I am on v5.7 as well. Where you able to get the query to run in to a few ms? I was able to get it down to between 2-3 secs, but haven't tried your indexes yet.

Comment: I had an execution time of about 4 secs without and .2 secs with the indexes i mentioned. But I don't dare to give much on that. On the plus side it ran on a 12 year old notebook which was middle class, when it was new and I also use as a desktop. So a dedicated server can presumably cope better. On the other hand the database server is just for some testing and didn't really do much. So especially the pressure on the system buffer might be very low compared to a server with realistic load and thus more (expensive) disk IO.

Comment: @stickybit I can't thank you enough, I've been stuck on this one for a few days now and had no idea why it was so slow. I can confirm your speed of `~2-3 ms` I guess my indexing was just not correct, whether single index, or multi column. It seems what you did to know which indexes to use was create 2 compound indexes based on the two left joins, "reversing" their fields, and leave the primary id index as is. I would have never guessed the reversal would be that useful, and surprised there where non on `nf.created_at > uf.created_at` or `notifiable_id` both in where clause.

Comment: If you add an answer I will mark as accepted. Thank you so much for the right indexes, this was a really difficult one to figure out!

Comment: btw, for `notification_followers` you only have a primary index, and dropped the others indexes there too correct?

Comment: Please see my answer. And I can confirm: I got his result with all the other indexes dropped. (It was only the two I mentioned and the `PRIMARY`s on `notification_followers` and `user_follows`.)

Comment: Check here, if this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58870915/3819751

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary from the comments:**

So far I'm getting the best result with

```
CREATE INDEX nfr_fid_nuuid
             ON notification_followers_read
                (follower_id,
                 notification_uuid);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX uf_fid_lid
             ON user_follows
                (follower_id,
                 leader_id);
```

and all the other indexes, except the primary ones, dropped. For `notification_followers` it used the `PRIMARY` index with me. I couldn't find anything better than `PRIMARY` for this table so far.

Tests were done on a MySQL v5.7.21 32 bit on Windows 7 32 bit.

Execution times were about 4 secs without and .2 secs with the indexes as stated above.

**Some lines on how, why and whatever:** (haven't had the space for that in the comments)

(Disclaimer: My knowledge on that shouldn't be All bad overall. Though, in some aspects my understanding might be improvable or just plainly wrong. Anyone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong somewhere -- edits or comments welcome.)

*A general thing about joins in terms of performance:*

As already mentioned in the comments, one goal with joins is to keep the sets joined as small as possible, as early as possible. For illustration: In the worst case, when a nested loop join must be applied, an `A JOIN B` needs *#A*#B* (let *#A* be the number of rows in *A*, analog for *B*) comparison operations. So any row from *A* (or *B*), which can be ruled out before the actual join operation is applied, will reduce the number of operations not only by *1* but by *#B* (or *#A*). One would want that in terms of performance.

If a join can be done via an index, especially in a way, that the DBMS can easily localize the portion of the index relevant for the join (i.e. keeping the set small), that can be a huge booster. Of course there are some other advantages an index can provide here (e.g.: the rows are already accessible in a sorted manner supporting more efficient join methods, the index might be significantly smaller and fit largely into memory thus reducing the need for constant disk IO, ...).

But all that is a topic on it's own, so this is just meant as a rough abstract.

*On the query the question is about:*

Now first thing to notice about the query: It is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (OK actually it's two but that doesn't matter for this thought). `notification_followers` is the left table here, so its set of records won't get reduced by the joins, just the `WHERE` can do that.

The `WHERE` unfortunately is an `OR`. These are difficult and "bad" in contrast to `AND`. It is more like a union hence keeping the set large, than like an intersect reducing the set's cardinality (Compare: For `A OR B` the result set is all rows `WHERE A UNION` all rows `WHERE B` in contrast to `A AND B` for which the result set is the all rows `WHERE A INTERSECT` all rows `WHERE B`).

So the `WHERE` isn't a too promising target to be answered from one index alone in a single run. Furthermore one of the `OR`ed operations from the `WHERE` (`nf.created_at > uf.created_at`) depends on the joined data, so that one can only be applied after (or at best while) the join.

There is also the `ORDER BY` which can be expensive especially, when the result set is too large to be kept in memory. It then needs to be sorted with constantly writing and reading from the disk (for a larger buffer). And disk access takes a lot of time.

So my hope for `notification_followers` was to find a compound index, that would support the `ORDER` and ideally at least one of the `OR`ed comparisons. As mentioned I failed on that. But my expectations also weren't too high on that, given the discussion on that part above.

Or `PRIMARY` is just good enough for that in the view of the DBMS, which might be fine. As I understand tables with a primary key in InnoDB are actually stored as [clustered indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_clustered_index). What I couldn't find (quickly) in the docs was, if the records are also double linked in order by the primary key. That would allow `PRIMARY` to support the `ORDER` by a reverse traverse of that linked list and make `PRIMARY` a good choice indeed.

The `ON`s of the joined tables are rather easy in contrast to the `WHERE` and the `ORDER`. (Exemplary I will use the join with `user_follows`, `notification_followers_read` is analog.) Here we have two relevant columns, `leader_id` and `follower_id`.

`follower_id` seems to be more suitable for the first column of a compound index. It's compared with a literal, hence independent of the partner rows of the join. The relevant portion of the index, a subtree -- "normal" indexes in MySQL are [some B tree variant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-structure.html) -- can thus be (re)used for all join partners. And also note the reduction of the set of possible rows from `user_follows` here!

Also having `leader_id` as a column in that index should then make the `user_follows`'s part of the join answerable from this index alone. And indeed it worked.

Note, that the order of the columns in the statement isn't necessarily the same for an index on them. Whatever is commutable is commuted by the optimizer, if it promises to be better. So the order won't be necessarily kept anyway. To find a good order of columns for an index one must mainly think about what order would partition the index in a most "radical" fashion first (leaving the remaining part as small as possible).

Comment: This is a really great explanation, thank you for taking the time to type up this detailed answer. It really helped me so much and I now understand a bit more why the query time shrunk drastically. You ended my 5 day frustration with this issue and for that I am awarding you 100 point bounty as a thank you as soon as SO lets me. Thank you so much again sticky bit. You're awesome!!

Comment: So it seems the query was slow when it was a user that was not `14`, I also read that `OR` is slow, and better to use `UNION`. So I split the query into two subqueries (both using indexes), with `UNION`. One of them is very fast, the other, really slow **~9 secs** So I created a question here with the slow query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476360/mysql-how-to-optimize-query-with-indexes Also we had to add a `follow_status` to the `user_follows` table. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 2):

Do not blindly use `LEFT`.  I think that the first `LEFT` is wrong, and the second can be reformulated as follows.

```
SELECT  nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id,
        nf.data, nf.created_at,
        ( SELECT  read_at
            FROM  notification_followers_read
            WHERE  nf.uuid = notification_uuid
              AND  follower_id = 14 
        ) AS read_at
    FROM  notification_followers nf
    JOIN  user_follows uf  ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id
    WHERE  (nf.created_at > uf.created_at
              OR  nf.notifiable_id = 14 
           )
      AND  uf.follower_id = 14
    ORDER BY  nf.id DESC
    LIMIT  10
```

`ON` should show how the tables are related, and not include filtering criteria.

Indexes:

```
notification_followers_read:
       INDEX(notification_uuid, follower_id,  -- in either order
             read_at)   -- last (to make it 'covering')
user_follows:
       INDEX(leader_id, follower_id,  -- in either order
             created_at)   -- last
```

(These indexes do not disagree with stickbit's, but they improve on them.)

Comment: Thanks for jumping in, I tried your query, but if you compare yours with the original, it seems your query results are missing the first `id` `100001`

Comment: It was also ~5-6s as opposed to the other query ~25ms (both queries using your indexes)